# Get item from Observable in Angular 2 with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, typescript1.8

I am trying to get an item from an observable in Angular 2 that's provided by a service. So far I can subscribe to the observable and see the contents in the console but cannot filter out an item by it's ID. I have tried the following below but get a blank screen. Any tips appreciated.

service.ts:

```
getJobs() {
  this.observableData = this._http.get('json_path/')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .do(val => {
        this.result = val;
        this.observableData = null;
      })
      .share();
  return this.observableData;
}
```

component.ts:

```
let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
this._jobService.getJobs().map(jobs => jobs.filter(item => item.id === id).subscribe(job => this.job = job)[0]);
```

Comment: Is this intentional. You posted the `getItems()` method and then use the `getJobs()` method below.

Comment: Ah, that was a mistake. They should both be either getItems() or getJobs(). Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
let id = this._routeParams.get('id');
this._jobService.getJobs().map(jobs => {
  return jobs.filter(item => item.id === id)[0];
}).subscribe(job => this.job = job));
```

You can't subscribe to the result of `jobs.filter()`

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me - the variables returned as undefined or empty. Although the code ran error-free in the console so the syntax looks correct :) I'll keep tweaking it. Thanks.

Comment: I got it working by moving the [0] index to the result of `jobs.filter()` instead of  `.subscribe()`.

    `this._jobService.getJobs().map(jobs => {
    return jobs.filter(item => item.id === id)[0]; 
    }).subscribe(job => this.job = job);`